# Grails - Filterpane associatedProperties

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

In a typical case for foll. domain class is it possible to apply filter parameters based on associated properties..

Domain class :

```
  Transaction{ 

     String dcNumber; 

     String status; 

     Customer fromCustomer; 

     Customer toCustomer; 

     static belongsto = Customer
```

}

in list.gsp i've applied filterpane as,

```
                       <filterpane:filterPane domain="Transaction"   

                           associatedProperties="fromCustomer.customerName,toCustomer.customerName"                               
                           filterPropertyValues="${[ 
                                   'fromCustomer.customerName':[values: com.test.Customer.list()], 
                                   'toCustomer.customerName':[values: com.test.Customer.list()] 
                               ]}" 
                        />
```

Now while filtering i can see only `fromCustomer` in filterpane, another parameter  `toCustomer` is **not at all considered/visible**, am i missing anything..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using filterpane plugin - 2.1.3 after i upgraded it to 2.3.1 the above said issue resolved perfectly.